# Make Summary Report Jmeter output in CSV what it shows in table

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

The Filename given to store the results of Jmeter Summary report  should (as I understand) store the same info I see on the screen . But instead it stores a short response of  the HTTP request sent like this :

```
<httpSample t="72" lt="66" ts="1305479685437" s="true" lb="login" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Virtual users 1-1" dt="text" by="12978">
```

I defined the Filename as a .csv file

Any idea how to turn it into a replica of the screen Summary report ( sample, average, Min, Max,Std.Dev etc)  ?

[image: get this report]

Answer (score 4):

To make a summary report of the JMeter output you need to do the following:

Make sure that in the **jmeter.properties** file the 'Results file configuration' is not in comment and all the fields you want to use are marked as true as shown below.

```
<pre><code>
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Results file configuration
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # This section helps determine how result data will be saved.
    # The commented out values are the defaults.

    # legitimate values: xml, csv, db.  Only xml and csv are currently supported.
    jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv


    # true when field should be saved; false otherwise

    # assertion_results_failure_message only affects CSV output
    #jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
    #
    # legitimate values: none, first, all
    #jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=none
    #
    jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false
    jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
    jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
</code></pre>
```

Then configure the Summary Report by clicking on **Configure** button.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, if you want to turn it into a replica of the screen Summary report ( sample, average, Min, Max,Std.Dev etc) just click the **Save Table Data** button and then save it as .csv format.

[image]

You will get .csv file like this :

[image]

Comment: this seems like a reasonable answer to me, and in fact, the answer I came here for.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Button is bottom of screen and barely noticable.

Answer (score 2):

Jp@gc has command-line tool for exporting jmeter reports to csv. Feed saved jtl file to it and use Aggregate report mode.
See. [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool docs](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) for help